# how a sizeof works when array name is passed

Tags: c, pointers, sizeof

Why sizeof(array_name) is the size of the array and sizeof(&a[0]) is the size of pointer even though, when an array name is passed to a function, what is passed is the location of the beginning of the array.

Comment: Because that's what the C spec stipulates. An array does not decay to a pointer when passed to `sizeof`, unless you make it so (as in `&a[0]`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In most expressions, when an array is used, it is automatically converted to a pointer to its first element.

There is a special rule for `sizeof`: When an array is an operand of `sizeof`, it is not automatically converted to a pointer. Therefore, `sizeof array_name` gives the size of the array, not the size of a pointer.

This rule also applies to the unary `&` operator : `&array_name` is the address of the array, not the address of a pointer.

Also, if an array is a string literal used to initialize an array, it is not converted to a pointer. The string literal is used to initialize the array.

The rule for this is C 2018 6.3.2.1 3:

> Except when it is the operand of the **sizeof** operator, or the unary **&** operator, or is a string literal used to initialize an array, an expression that has type "array of *type*" is converted to an expression with type "pointer to *type*" that points to the initial element of the array object and is not an lvalue. If the array object has register storage class, the behavior is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Array parameters to functions don't exist. They turn into pointers (the innermost index does, if the array is multidimensional). It's just syntactic sugar inherited from the B language. `void f(int *X) == void f(int X[]);`

(Same for function params to functions. `void g(void X(void)) == void g(void (*X)(void))`).